# Print CSS with pdf included in page

Tags: pdf, print-css

I have a page where I have a lot of info about an item, with a little "Download specs pdf" button below. Clicking it opens the pdf seperately, which is all I need for the webversion.

However I'm currently working on my print css, and my goal is to create a print css here that shows the info along with the pdf below it, included in the same printfile.

Is it possible to embed the pdf in my page (only for print css)? I've tried using the `<object>` or `embed` tags but this doesn't seem to show up at all in my print css.

Update: I managed to show the pdf using `iframe`, but I'm unable to set the iframe height to the pdf's height. The pdf is dynamic so it's not a set height. Dynamically updating the height through jQuery has proven to be impossible because the onload event isn't fired for file downloads in an iframe. If anyone can help me come to a solution, I would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @Noseratio Yes, preferably. But atm I'm not even getting it to work in any browser.

Comment: I think the problem of setting height is bigger than just onload event, if you try to do it on settimeout of 1000 ms, would it work? There is noway you can tell the height of the pdf inside the iframe, it usualy goes the other way around anyway, you let the body of the iframe content fire a load signal to resize its containing iframe. Alas, PDF does not have an "onload" event inside.. does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to force a 4:3 perspective on the iframe and size it according to your print page (A4 paper size is standard here).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me and helping me in the chat earlier ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDF.js library's who is an amaZing JavaScript PDF viewer working cross browser. Display the PDF in a div, make it hidden with a display:none for web version with your screen CSS.

Answer (score 1):

One advice I can give you is, if you know the maximum number of PDF pages, just make the iframe height large enough... that means, if the number of pages is less, the printer is going to output empty pages.

The other advice was the one stated above, get a tool to annotate or change properties of all PDFs to contain that information.

I found this tool: http://pdfcrowd.com/html-to-pdf-api/ to convert PDF into HTML, which you can use instead of displaying PDF

Comment: This is what I went with in the end, after someone pointed out the pdf in the iframe will automatically scale itself to 100% of the given static width/height. This worked in my case, as the PDFs were all 1-page only. So I ended up setting the width/height in 3:4 ratio and successfully included it in the print page. An easy solution!

Comment: While it works in Chrome and FF, the pdf still doesn't seem to show up when I print it in IE, any clue?

Comment: you sure it didn't get pushed to a second print page?

Comment: Yes, since I printed 5 pages where the 3rd one should have been  the pdf. It just shows a blank spot though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your best bet is to have a parsed version of the PDF for printing. Open it in Illustrator and save each page to SVG and use the SVG files to print with.

Comment: I have over 200 products which get imported with their pdf dynamically. So this is not an option.

Comment: I'm sure there are tools out there that can dynamically convert PDF to SWF on the fly.

Comment: If your product PDF is fetched dynamically, maybe you want to include that information inside the PDF upon generation?

Comment: @Ayyash I don't understand what you mean. Include which information in which pdf?

Comment: I think @Ayyash is referring to personalizing the PDF, like having it say "Specially prepared for " + `clientName`. Any information in your database that could add value could be included in the PDF.

Comment: is their a db field that says: this is the link to the PDF? or is it more of a code that generates a PDF on the fly of the specs required?

Comment: @Ayyash It's a link to a static PDF, not a dynamically generated PDF.